# How to combine subtotal and sumif with a range of criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I'm trying to create a formula to combine a `SUMIF` (using a range of criteria) and a subtotal.

The `SUMIF` statement:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(E:E,O2:O21,G:G))
```

And where I've gotten on making that `SUMIF` subtotal:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(G2,ROW(G2:G5000)-ROW(G2),0)),(E2:E5000=O2:O21)+0)
```

That last statement returns an `#N/A` error. I'd appreciate any input y'all can provide.

Thank you.

Example:

```
Order  | Date  | Mach  | Rem 
-------|-------|-------|-------
A      |01/20  | 01    | 1200
B      |01/11  | 02    | 400
C      |01/21  | 01    | 420
D      |01/28  | 04    | 1180
E      |01/20  | 01    | 1200
F      |01/11  | 04    | 400
G      |01/21  | 03    | 420
H      |01/28  | 04    | 1180
```

No t sure I got the table right, so here's an image of what I see.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is filter based on the date - say, all orders that occur before 1/21 - and then give the amount remaining in a list of machines.

So, if I wanted the total from Machine 1 and 4, the output from that table (with the date filter on) would be 2800, summing order A, D, E, and F.  With the filter off it'd be 5580.

Comment: Perhaps you could include some of your data and show us what you are trying to do - i.e. what the formula should return

Comment: Use as array formula. Means Press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` after entering formula to cell.

Comment: So, what I've got is a list of machines, orders, quantities, and due dates.  The idea is to filter the list on the due dates, and return the quantity of the orders occurring on a specific list of machines.  I'm working on editing it into a the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($C:$C;J:J;0)))*SUBTOTAL(103;OFFSET(C1;ROW(C:C)-MIN(ROW(C:C));0));$D:$D)
```

Excel structure:
[image]

After applying a filter:
[image]

You can also include date criteria already in the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($C:$C;J:J;0)))*($B:$B<$L$1);$D:$D)
```

Where L1 is date criteria.

But, of course, if you need filter usage, use the first solution.

Comment: Thank you! The date filter varies weekly - it's for a report given to a very old-fashioned manager, by an old-fashioned scheduler - so I'll keep the date filter out of the formula.  I appreciate your help! I searched all over the place for help with this, but couldn't find anything that used more than 1 criteria in the sumif.